# Find specific item on icollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, icollection

I'm working on an web api and trying to find a product by it's name with icollection, specifically a product that would match the name given (?name={name}).

Currently I have this:

```
[HttpGet("name", Name = "GetProductByName")]
public ActionResult<Product> GetByName(string _name)
{
    var prod = (from x in _context.Products 
                where x.Name == _name 
                select x).FirstOrDefault();

    if (prod == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return prod;
}
```

But whenever I query the api (api/product/?name={name} I get all results

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Remainder of the controller since it's not a parameter mismatch. I am using an EF DbSet

```
[Route("api/Product")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly OrderingProductsContext _context;

    public ProductController(OrderingProductsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Product>> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Products.ToList();
    }


    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetProduct")]
    public ActionResult<Product> GetById(long id)
    {
        var prod = _context.Products.Find(id);
        if (prod == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return prod;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Product prod)
    {
        _context.Products.Add(prod);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetProduct", new { id = prod.ID }, prod);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the whole controller? You probably got another end-point to fulfill the api/product/?name={name} query.

Comment: your parameter is "_name" not "name" as i can see!

Comment: There's no `ICollection` in here. `_context` is most likely an EF DbContext. This will generate a database query. This code shouldn't even compile

Comment: Edited my question and posted the entire controller since the parameter mismatch didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @idetodospoca I suggest you put a breakpoint in your GetAll() method. I am pretty sure you make a request to that method but not GetByName. Also, your GetByName attribute missing curly brackets. It should be like [HttpGet("{name}"...

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `_name` as parameter but checking your condition with `name`

change

```
var prod = (from x in _context.Products where x.Name == name select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

with

```
var prod = (from x in _context.Products where x.Name == _name select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `_name` with `name` in your method definition. Based on the code you have posted is clear that the `where` clause doesn't make use of the parameter passed at each call of `GetByName` but the value of variable `name` is used.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use curly brackets in your attribute parameter;

```
[HttpGet("{name}", Name = "GetProductByName")]
```

Then you can call that endpoint with this;

```
 api/product/GetProductByName/{name}
```

Or if you want to call with query strings you can go with;

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetProductByName")]
public ActionResult<Product> GetByName([FromQuery]string name)
```

and request like ;

```
api/product/GetProductByName?name={name}
```